# implicit super constructor is undefined even with no arg constructor?

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor

So i'm new to Java, and I got this error saying that the constructor is undefined. I did some research and found that I needed to add a no arg constructor, however even after I did that I'm still getting and error.

```
import javax.swing.JComponent;


public abstract class Block extends JComponent{
    Block(){}
}
```

This is the super class that I don't have anything in just yet

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.Arrays;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Head extends Block{
    private int xpos;
    private int ypos;
    private boolean[] m;

    public Head(){
        xpos = getWidth()/2;
        ypos = getHeight()/2;
    }
}
```

This is the sub class that is giving the error :/

Comment: you didnot call super() in your constructor of Head?

Comment: @Hirak, He does not need to, that call should be implicit if omited.

Comment: Can you post the stack trace?

Comment: Your code compiles fine on my system. Without a `main`, I cannot reproduce any run-time errors.

Comment: The code compiles just fine... what error you are getting?

Comment: The error I'm getting is "Implicit super constructor Block() is undefined. Must explicitly invoke another constructor"

Comment: @MagnusCaligo, Add `public ` in front of the `Block()` constructor.

Comment: The strange thing is: If `Block` was defined in a different package such that the constructor would not be accessible due to the default modifier, it should show up in the `import`-list, no?

Comment: @MagnusCaligo even if you import but constructor is not accessible because it's not public/protected.Here Default access of constructor creates error `Implicit super constructor Block() is undefined` because Class Block is in different package

Answer (score 1):

Your no-arg constructor has the default modifiers - unless `Head` and `Block` are in the same package, `Head` won't be able to access it. You should define it as `public`:

```
public abstract class Block extends JComponent{
    public Block(){}
}
```

... or at least protected:

```
public abstract class Block extends JComponent{
    protected Block(){}
}
```

... or alternatively, not at all. This will cause Java to implicitly create a no-arg, empty constructor with `public` access rights:

```
public abstract class Block extends JComponent{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

it is not neccesary that you should have no argument constructor in your abstract class...you can have a parametrized constructor but then you have to call `super()` in the first line of your child class..here is the example....

```
import javax.swing.JComponent;


public abstract class Block extends JComponent{
    int height, width; // just for example only you can have anything you want
    Block(int h, int w){  //you can have anything as per you requirement
        height=h; width=w;
    }
}
```

& here is the child class.....

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.Arrays;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Head extends Block{
    private int xpos;
    private int ypos;
    private boolean[] m;

    public Head(int h, int w){
        super(h, w);  //note this step...you have to call the constructor of super class by using super(..); and remember to pass parameter..
        xpos = getWidth()/2;
        ypos = getHeight()/2;
    }
}
```

in the case you have just default no argument constructor...you just replace `super(h, w);` with `super();`.....think it will help you..